# CMake find Boost manually without environment variable

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

My project is monolithic and I have packed all my SDKs into a single folder in my project as follows:

```
ProjectName/Code/SDKs/asio/1.20.0/...
```

I usually find the libraries that are not header-only by the help of `find package`:

```
find_package(LIB ${LIB_USE_VERSION} EXACT REQUIRED PATHS "${LIB_DIR}")
```

These libraries usually have `LIBNAMEConfig.cmake` and `LIBNAMEConfig-version.cmake` to be found manually.

But things change when it comes to boost as I don't want to use environment variable for SDKs.

Comment: It is unclear to me what the problem is here. `set(BOOST_DIR path/to/Code/SDKs/boost-1.78.0) 
find_package(Boost 1.78.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)` or similar?

Comment: ***But things change when it comes to boost as I don't want to use environment variable for SDKs.*** How will you expect CMake to find this SDK folder in a non-standard location without either an environment variable some manual method?

Comment: When "PATHS" is defined, CMake does it without environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [pre-built libraries](https://boost.teeks99.com/) if you are not going to do any changes.

Let me know if it solves your problem.